# wordpress: tumbnail hover -> show title

Tags: php, wordpress, hover

I am currently creating my own wordpress theme. The index is a simple thumbnails grid. What I'm trying to do is showing the title of the article on mouse over. I want every title to be shown in the same div, like`<div id='article-title'> <?php the_title(); ?> </div>` becomes the title of any hover thumbnail. Is this even possible? If not, are there any alternatives?

this is the basic code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="tableau">
<div div="thumbnail">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(vignette); ?></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id='article-title'> <?php the_title(); ?> </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : 
while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="tableau">
        <div id="thumbnail" post_id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(vignette); ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='article-title'> <?php the_title(); ?> </div>

<?php endwhile;
  endif; ?>
```

and the js will be

```
<script> 
$("#thumbnail"). on("mouseover", function() {
var post_id = $(this).attr('post_id'); 
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: ajax_url,  // you need to provide ajax url here 
        data: {
            action: "get_post_title",
            ID: post_id
        },
        success:function(data){
            $("#article-title").html(data);
        },error: function(errorThrown){
           console.log(errorThrown);
        } 
    });

  })
</script >
```

and the functions.php code here.

```
<?php
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_post_title', 'delete_jobfn' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_title', 'delete_jobfn' );
 fucntion Kv_get_post_title(){
   wp_die(get_the_title( $_POST['ID'] )); 

  } ?>
```

I hope this will give you the solution

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Kvvaradha !

Comment: Is the ajax url something like "/wp-content/themes/theme_name/index.php" ? If yes, unfortunely it doesn't work. Nothing has changed, the div show the last article title. Maybe we should not use <?php the_title(); ?> and just call the title inside the div?

Comment: to be more precise, the div #article-title shows all the titles at the same time when in index.php, and only the title of the last article published when in footer (that's where I would like to place it)

Comment: Ajax url is different. it might be " http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"